# How can i select data from a Database with checkbox in Asp.net MVC?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

sorry but i'm new to asp.net and MVC.
I have a program that read data from a Database and display the result in an index page with a checkbox near every row:

```
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            Select
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Rep_Id)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Rep_Lot_Id)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Rep_PDFToCreate)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Rep_PDFCreated)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Rep_Status)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Rep_Type)
        </th>

    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.CheckBox("pdf", true)

            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Rep_Id)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Rep_Lot_Id)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Rep_PDFToCreate)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Rep_PDFCreated)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Rep_Status)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Rep_Type)
            </td>

        </tr>

    }

</table>

<script>
    function Obtain_Lot() {

        var name=...
    }
</script>
```

My goal is to create a button that when is clicked, it gets the "model.Rep_Lot_Id" of the item checked as a string. Only one item can be checked.  How can i do that?

Comment: you can use jquery to get the checkbox that have value is `checked`, then use the jquery `travel` function to get `Rep_Lot_Id`

Comment: Thank you, didn't know the function travel. I will search it and try if it works.

Answer (score 0):

i usually use this code in your case:

```
var checkedCheckbox = $("input:checked"); // consider only one checkbox can be checked
var repLotId = $(checkedCheckbox).parent().next().next().html(); // travel to the Rep_Lot_Id `td` and get its value.
```

Comment: Thanks, i have tried but when iprint the repLotId in a label for test it says that the variable is undefined.